# Underscore replace new line characters with line break

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, replace, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a micro-template bringing in strings from a rest call, but the strings are not formatted in the way they were originally entered.

The following works:

```
<%= message.replace(new RegExp('\d', 'g'), '<br /><br />') %>
```

However, this allows scripts to be entered and will execute when the template is shown. I also tried this:

```
<%- message.replace(new RegExp('\d', 'g'), '<br /><br />') %>
```

But this just prints `<br />` text in the html. Basically I need a combination of the two, allowing the template to create the new line without letting scripts entered from the rest call through.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you're putting text in a HTML element and want to display that text including line-breaks, just set `white-space: pre-wrap;` in element's styles.

Comment: @hon2a oh wow, don't know how that didn't occur to me. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are instantiating a new `RegExp` object from a string pattern, you have to escape `\d`:

```
new RegExp('\\d', 'g')
```

Doing `new RegExp('\d', 'g')` is the same as `/d/g`.